# How to take snapshots with LVM?

Tags: gnome, lvm, snapshot

This time when I installed Ubuntu off my LiveUSB I ticked the option to also install LVM for easier snapshot taking and partition resizing. But now even after looking in the LVM man page, I am still unsure of how to take a snapshot with it. So that is really my question, how do you use LVM to take snapshots on Ubuntu GNOME 15.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `lvcreate` command along with the `--snapshot` option to take a snapshot.
To define the size add the `--size` option and to set a name add the `--name` option.
Select drive/partition/directory/folder where you want to store the snapshot.

Find more command line options from the Ubuntu lvcreate manual [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man8/lvcreate.8.html).

And I found an excellent guide on to how use lvm snapshots for backups on [tutonics](http://www.tutonics.com/2012/12/lvm-guide-part-2-snapshots.html)

Comment: That site doesn't seem to like my machine, nor my machine it... So could you please put its contents into your answer. :) Also link-only answers are normally detect by the system as low quality and then deleted.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @RolandiXor - I couldn't have explained it better without copying something from the tutorial. I followed your suggestion and added details in my own words - Thank you !

Comment: What would it mean to define the size?

Comment: The size the snapshot will have - e.g. --size 5GB (has to be large enough to not run out of space). :)

Comment: By the way, putting it into your own words is good, but you can also quote the tutorial and give a link back to it...