# How to "keep" data from an LVM snapshot?

Tags: lvm

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/673365/how-to-take-snapshots-with-lvm) deals with creating LVM snapshots but doesn't detail what to do with them afterwards.

For example, let's suppose I have a volume group (`vgpool`) and a logical volume (`lvboot`). I create a snapshot of the volume (`lvboot-snap`) like so:

```
lvcreate --size 1G --snapshot --name lvboot-snap /dev/vgpool/lvboot
```

What commands do I run to:

- revert everything to the way it was *before* the snapshot?
- preserve everything written *after* the snapshot and remove the snapshot?

Comment: Did you mean preserve everything written into the snapshot or preserve everything written into the original volume?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

- To discard the snapshot you just remove the volume using `sudo` [`lvremove`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man8/lvremove.8.html) `vgpool/lvboot-snapshot`. Make sure it is not mounted before attempting to remove it.
- To undo the changes made since the snapshot was taken and delete the snapshot use `sudo` [`lvconvert`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man8/lvconvert.8.html) `--merge vgpool/lvboot-snap`, then reboot. (The operation will be performed at boot before mounting the filesystem.)

Comment: The third part is grossly incorrect, per manual page and practice, the split snapshot option merely separates the COW data into a standalone DM_snapshot_cow LV, it doesn't actually create an LV containing usable data

Answer (score 2):

`lvconvert --merge` does NOT "keep the changes made since the snapshot was taken" - it destroys those changes!

To understand why, you have to realize that, in LVM, a snapshot stores changes made to the original volume since it was taken. This is why it is a COW (Copy on Write) snapshot - the original volume is written as usual, but the original data is Copied into the snapshot prior to the Write.

So:

- To discard all the data since the snapshot - that is, to "roll back" to when the snapshot was taken: `lvconvert --merge vgpool/lvboot-snap` (it will take a while)
- To stop writing to the snapshot because you are happy with the original LV at this time: `lvremove vgpool/lvboot-snap` (it will happen almost instantly)

Please be careful and don't lose your data. At the time of this writing, the previous answer states the opposite. Please see [this other answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/41020/is-this-how-lvm-snapshots-work/41202#41202) for a detailed explanation.